# Searching ALL ROWS in a Group using IIF Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, iif

I am working on a report that displays patient names (as groups with drilldowns) and several fields related to their visits.  I have created a column in the report to display whether or not a specific value appears in the 'LocationID' column.  The expression I used is

=IIF(Fields!LocationID.Value="WELL","Y","N")

I thought this was working great, it displays Y or N next to each name to let me know if 'WELL' was in their 'LocationID'. I checked several to ensure that this was going to work and discovered that there was a LocationID code of 'WHS' and since I have the rows ordered by Name and LocationID if there was a WHS visit it shows up at the top of the group and my expression is only seeing this top item.  How can this expression be written differently so that it searches the entire result of each group?  Depending on the date range a patient may have one visit or they may have ten.  I need to check all visits that are returned.  Perhaps there is a better method.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would do this in SQL using a case statement to create a flag for your dataset based on the logic you need. - So eg: case when LocationID = 'blah' then 'Y' when LocationID = 'blah' then 'N' else 'blah' end as [newFlag]

Comment: That would work fine except wouldn't it return the Y or N value for each record. I just need to know for each patient if their visits include this value or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with jimmy8ball that the easiest way to solve most issues like this is to push some logic back into the SQL layer.

However, if you really want to do this via SSRS functionality, then you could implement a substring search against a lookupset. Assuming you have a patient id in your dataset that is unique for each patient (I hope your group isn't on the name) then...

```
=Iif(InStr(Join(Lookupset(Fields!patientid.Value, Fields!patientid.Value, Fields!LocationsID.Value, "dataset"), ","), "WELL") > 0, "Y", "N")
```

Which says, "Search through the dataset for all rows related to my patientid, join every location into a comma deliminated string, search the string for the text "WELL" and return "Y" if it's found.

Obviously if you have locations in your dataset like "WELLY", these will become false positives and you'll have to implement some more nested logic.  Try appending a value (perhaps !) to the lookupset return field so that you can search for "WELL!" or some other terminator character.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was able to work through this using a CASE statement as suggested previously.  I appreciate the feedback.